# How to have users change their passwords after the first login?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

The website that I have created requires to have Admin accounts create accounts for users. How would I go about having those users change their password after the first time they login? The problem is users will have a generic password designated to them, after they decide to login for the first time I would like them to have to change their password to something that is less generic.

**Here is my login controller**

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }

        }
```

**My login Model**

```
 public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }



}
```

**And the view**

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: How do you think you would go about it?

Comment: Just like Windows itself does it; create a column in your database named appropriately (like `mustChangePassword`) then simply check if that's set when the user logs in. If it is set, force them to reset their password.

Comment: Do you have an specific issue or you just want advice on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Create new field in the Database `ChangePassword` in the `[User]` Table, default value
   equals to 1.
2. When the new user log in make check if this user have field
   `ChangePassword = 1`.
3. If the user should change password, redirect him to page `ChangePasswordPage` in other case redirect to your default page.
4. When he fill new password and click `Change Password` Button, set ChangePassword flag in `[User]` table to 0 and redirect him to your default page.

Comment: An often practical problem here is that user is usually logged on by the time it's detected that they need to change password. So instead of changing the password they simply can paste a web site page into the address bar and go about their business without changing password. So there should be a good way to detect that password is not changed *on every single page*.

Answer (score 16):

I've just had a similar problem. My system has the option of an admin creating users. What I did was to create the user with a randomly generated password.

The Confirmation Email normally has a URL which contains the email confirmation token. All I did was to include the confirmation AND email reset tokens:

```
string emailConfirmationCode = await 
UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userID);
        string passwordSetCode = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userID);


var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = userID, emailConfirmationCode = emailConfirmationCode, passwordSetCode = passwordSetCode }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(userID, subject,$"Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"{callbackUrl}\">here</a>");
```

then, in my confirmEmail action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string emailConfirmationCode, string passwordSetCode = null )
{
    if (userId == null || emailConfirmationCode == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, emailConfirmationCode);

    if (result.Succeeded && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordSetCode))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = userId, code = passwordSetCode, firstPassword = true  });
    }

    return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
}
```

Note that I use firstPassword so that I can show a different view to Forgot Password

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code, bool firstPassword = false)
{
    if (code == null)
        return View("Error");
    return firstPassword? View("FirstPassword") : View();
}
```

This way, the only way they can log in is by confirming their email AND setting their password. IF they somehow don't follow through with the reset, they'd need to do the forgot password process from scratch. Re-clicking their link gives me a token error the second time around.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: I love this solution.  I tweaked it by passing the email address since I am reusing the ResetPasswordConfirmation page and just updating the message/hiding the email address textbox.

Comment: That's a pretty nice solution. I wonder, though, if we should do something if the user let the password reset token expire. Is it better to have a workaround for that? Or simply let the user go to forgot password?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a database field tracking his last logged in, it would be easy to implement a simple solution like this:

1. First time they come with a generic password, last logged in field will be null.
2. You can check if the last logged in field is null, they have never changed their password, so you can force them to change it (you can check if new password is not the same as before) and let them login as well. Now user has last logged in date set to not null. He is now set to login with new password going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Force them to change their password. As long as they haven't changed there "once-off" password, no access to the site. let them type 2 their new password, check if they are equal, then update their password. 
Somewhere,probably in your database you have to keep track if they havechanged their once-off password.